# Is better to use a for over a list or multiple access to database

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having a doubt over the better implementation of a method that is often used.
The solution in production as the following form:

```
public List<Element> method(String text) {  
        List<Element> element = select * from element e where e.text like text
        return element
        }
```

the new implementation instead load the complete list 1 time

```
List<Element> allElement =select * from element
```

and the method become something like

```
    public List<Element> method(String text) {  
        List<Element> element; 
        for Element e : allElement{
          if e.text.contains(text) element.add(e)
        }
        return element
        }
```

Which one is the better solution?

Comment: If you can filter in the Database via a where clause you should do it. That's what databases are made and optimized for. Trying to load everything from a database at once can also easily  bring your memory to its knees if you are dealing with a big database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach looks better , as you are leveraging DB functionality to filter the result(Which is more optimised to do that task).
Second approach significantly increases the roundtrip time required to fetch all the elements(depending on number of elements)and added time complexity as you are looping through whole list and also it might consume more memory on your application

Answer (score 0):

Its much better to get all the data in one go. This is because you don't need to waste time on TCP/IP packet roundtrips to the database each time.

At the same time, be aware that if the result set you are trying to load in one go is too big you can get an `OutOfMemory` error.

In short:

- Getting data in one go is better
- Be sure that you have enough RAM on the JVM to accomodate the (potentially) large data set.

Comment: Even in first approach data is fetched in one go ,only difference is that first approach is utilising DB functionality to filter the results.